# Why the breakpoint does not work for any methods of the "PlatformDispatcher" class in flutter?

Tags: flutter, sdk, frameworks, internals

I am learning the flutter framework internally. So I want to see the binding methods captured from the framework and specifically `scheduleFrame()` method. But the program does not capture the breakpoint. I configured to debug `Debug my code + packages + sdk`.

[image]

[image]